# In a tripartite network in networkX in Python, is there a way to find most connected node in each layer?

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

I have a network which is stored as a networkX graph G. It is undirected so has three layers and there are connections between nodes each layer. Is there a way to find most connected node in each layer e.g. for each node to find how many connections are coming to it/going out from it (I imagine these are the same for undirected graphs?) and therefore rank them somehow. For the middles layer, what's needed is to know how often a node is connected to any of the nodes in the left layer and right layer separately. An image of the network is below. Can I assign that as the node size as well?. Similarly for the line width of the graph to be controlled by how often a connection is made in the data. Thanks. [image]

Edited:
I've found the information from the data which forms this network. Now with this information, how can I assign the edge weight in the bokeh plot. I'm creating edges from the edge tuple column. Similarly, I have a node list with their node weight/size depending on frequency as well.

```
df.head()
Index Edge-tuple    Edge-weight
0   (dFac-1637903094, vcFac-1679993405) 9
1   (dFac--1093622611, vcFac--641939347)    8
2   (dFac-2117005857, vcFac-1094947741) 7
3   (dFac-1922215824, vcFac--802250542) 7
4   (dFac--1444346401, vcFac--1590094556)   6
```

Comment: Provide some code so that we know what you tried... If you already have the information which node is in which layer this should be an easy task.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some progress to the question with some sample of data.